# Smooth scheme over a field is reduced, why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Could someone tell mey why this is true:

> A smooth scheme over a field is regular and hence normal. In particular, a smooth scheme over a field is reduced.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_scheme#Properties]

I suppose that this comes from the property  `normal` but I don't see the connection.

Comment: You can skip "normal" here and just focus on "regular": any regular local ring is a UFD (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslander%E2%80%93Buchsbaum_theorem), in particular a domain. So it does not have nilpotents.

Comment: As a follow-up question: At what point does the statement fail over a (discrete valuation) ring instead of a field?

Comment: Dear reinbot, I am afraid I don't know the answer. In fact, I would expect a smooth scheme over a DVR to be regular, but I cannot provide any details right now.